# How to pull information from an array and manipulate the data before storing it again in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Lets say I have the following associative array

```
$epl = array('Chelsea'=>array('gf'=>32,'ga'=>12,'pts'=>22),
             'ManCity'=>array('gf'=>43,'ga'=>20,'pts'=>18));
```

what if I want to update the pts data with some function where I would want to pull the current 22 points that Chelsea has and add 3 more points for another win and then store 25 back in that position. How would I do that? Can the following be done?

> $newpts = $epl['Chelsea']['pts'] + 3;
>
> $epl['Chelsea']['pts'] = $newpts;

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply just do this:

```
$epl['Chelsea']['pts'] += 3;
```

This will add 3 to the existing value and store it in the same place. This is the equivalent of writing this line:

```
$epl['Chelsea']['pts'] = $epl['Chelsea']['pts'] + 3;
```

The [`+=` and `-=` operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) both work in-place, so += will add the value to the right to the variable on the left and store it in the variable on the left, and -= will subtract the value on the right from the variable on the left and store it in the variable on the left.

Comment: i was hoping it was just something simple like that...thanks a lot